# jQuery.trigger() not firing on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an html page, `Home.htm`, that contains an iframe which holds another page `Child.htm`, i.e.

```
<body>
   <div>
      <iframe id="child-iframe" src="Child.htm"></iframe>
   </div>
</body>
```

`Home.htm` also contains some `javascript/jQuery` that retrieves data and depending on this data retrieves more information and then triggers an event set up in the `Child.htm` file to display this information within `Child.htm`, i.e.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $.getJSON("http://getsummarydata/001")
         .done(function (data) {
             if (data meets some condition) {
                 $.getJSON("http://getspecificdata/001")
                    .done(function (data) {
                       // Trigger the event
                       var target = $("#child-iframe");
                       if (target[0] !== undefined) {                   
                           target[0].contentWindow.$(target[0].contentWindow.document).trigger("data-available", [data]);
                       }
                 });
             }                
         }
   });
</script>
```

Within `Child.htm` I have set up the custom event, `data-available`, and its handler using `jQuery` as follows;

```
<script>

   // Event handler
   function myFunc(data) {
      // Display the data
   }

   // Event
   $(document).on('data-available', function (__e, __data) {
      myFunc(__data);
   });

</script>
```

When the `Home.htm` page is first loaded the data is retrieved succesfully, the event is triggered and the data is displayed as expected within the iframe. However, when I refresh the `Home.htm` (F5), the data is still retreived but the trigger is no longer fired - infact I get the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: target[0].contentWindow.$ is not a function
```

Even though target[0].contentWindow seems ok.

I don't know why this happening on a refresh and any help with resolving this would be much appreciated.

Paul

Comment: How do you `// Display the data`?

Comment: Can you console.log the value of target[0].contentWindow.document.readyState when the error occurs

Comment: I also think that this is a timing issue, because the parent window starts doing stuff while the child window is still loadng. Maybe you can reverse the logic and let the child window request the Data from it's host once it's loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your events are firing before the iframe has completely loaded. That would explain why it can't find `$` when it needs it, but it is there when you inspect it. One potential reason might be that your data requests are cached and so return almost immediately.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what's happening.